# c dual LAN socket programming

Tags: c, sockets

```
int  udp_sock()
      {
    size_t size=sizeof(server);

               //Create socket
                  sock = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_DGRAM , IPPROTO_UDP);


                  if (sock == -1)
                  {
                      printf("Could not create socket\n");
                  }
                  puts("Socket created.......\n");


                  server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.210.9");
                  server.sin_family = AF_INET;
                  server.sin_port = htons(4000);
                             // Connect to remote server
              client.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.210.48");
                                      client.sin_family = AF_INET;
                                      client.sin_port = htons(4000);

                  if(bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &client, sizeof(client)) < 0) {
                                          perror("bind failed\n");
                  }
                  puts("Connected\n");

                  n=sendto(sock,buffer,strlen(buffer),0,(struct sockaddr *)&server,size);
                  return 0;
      }

int  udp_sock1()
      {
    size_t size=sizeof(server);

               //Create socket
                  sock = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_DGRAM , IPPROTO_UDP);


                  if (sock == -1)
                  {
                      printf("Could not create socket\n");
                  }
                  puts("Socket created.......\n");

                  memset(&server, 0, sizeof(server));
                  server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.210.60");
                  server.sin_family = AF_INET;
                  server.sin_port = htons(5000);
                  client.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.210.48");
                                                      client.sin_family = AF_INET;
                                                      client.sin_port = htons(4000);

                                  if(bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &client, sizeof(client)) < 0) {
                                                          perror("bind failed\n");
                                  }
                                  puts("Connected\n");
                                rc=recvfrom(sock, buffer,1024 , 0,(struct sockaddr *)&client,&size);

                                  return 0;
      }
```

1.I am working on dual LAN PC. I have to receive data from `192.168.210.60 port no. 5000` as defined in `udp_sock1()` above.
And send the received data to `192.168.210.9 with port 4000` defined in `udp_sock`.
my system IP is `192.168.210.48 port 4000`.

plz guide.

Comment: Do you get any errors? I don't know much about c or sockets, but what I know is that SO isn't a "please code for me website". So please narrow down where you need help.

Comment: I'd not get into solving your probem. But the way your program can be structured is - your program is a server for `192.168.210.60:5000` and client for `192.168.210.9:4000`. And you mention your port to be `192.168.210.48:4000` so you should be listening on that. This should help you get started

Comment: Unless the subnet mask is really tight, all the addresses given are on the same LAN segment?

Comment: if i am recieving as a client and sending data back as a client,is it correct ??